# Does Laravel Task Scheduling need to proc_open and proc_close?

Tags: php, laravel, php-ini

I'm using laravel task scheduling in my project to run cron jobs.
I have two question.

first: Does `Laravel Task Scheduling` need to `proc_open` and `proc_close`?

and second: removing `proc_open` and `proc_close` from `disabled_functions` in `php.ini` does not make security issue ?